# Get Loop Key Inside Vue SFC

Tags: vue.js

Given the following looping component:

```js
<MyComponent v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :item="item" />
```

How do I get the value of `key` within `MyComponent` obviously `key` is a reserved word so it fails to work as a prop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as a declared prop (e.g: `index`):

```html
<MyComponent v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" :item="item" :index="i" />
```

MyComponent.vue:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    index: Number
  }
}
```

---

Side note: it's recommended you `key` lists using a unique identifier (e.g: `id`) rather than based on their position in the list. For example, if any items get replaced or updated, Vue might not re-render, because the items' position in the array has not changed, even if the item itself has.

This is why list transitions don't work when you key items by index.

However, if your items don't change position and/or do not get updated, `index` as `key` does the job.

Comment: Thanks. The index of the items passed in are strings not numbers, so it's not a position in the list. I was trying to avoid duplicating the the props but it's all good, strange that there's not a built in way to access that key since it is technically a prop. Weird. But thanks.

Comment: @Vince, It's not a prop. The template is parsed by Vue and various keys get parsed differently. Some are events, some are directives, some are attributes and some properties. `:key` is used internally, it's not passed to the actual HTML output element.

Comment: Also note `:index="i"` passes the `i` defined by `v-for` (a `0` based `index`, a **number**). So the first item will get an `index` value of `0` (not `'0'`), second will get `1` (not `'1'`), etc... This `index` passed to the child component is different than what you might have in `item.index` (which might be strings, if defined - you haven't shared the structure of an `item`).

Comment: I don't think that's true, `i` will be whatever the key values of the array are, if I loop through this without the component, just in an unordered list for example, and I print out `i` like `{{ i }}` I get the keys of my array, NOT a number. Give it a try.

Comment: Why don't you print out `{{ typeof i }}` instead of `{{ i }}`? Object keys are strings. Array keys are numbers. In JavaScript, at least. `console.log(['a', 'b'].map((item, key) => typeof key)`. `0` is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). `'0'` is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). `console.log(1 + 1) // 2`. `console.log('1' + '1') // '11'`.